# Error remains after applying fix_shape: ValueError: slice index 0 of dimension 0 out of bounds

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I'm trying to build a Neural Network with Tensorflow and I got really stuck there.

Here's what the network is being meant to accomplish:
A bunch of Pdfs with different contents has been converted to numpy arrays in the shape (22,512,512,3).

In each Pdf the first 22 pages were rendered into a 512x512px numpy array and saved as .npy file.

The Network is supposed detect the classification of a Pdf, for example drawings or instructions.

This basically works with a smaller amount of Pdfs which can be converted into numpy arrays in the RAM. But since there are about 100GB of learn data, I decided to map the preprocessed numpy files.

This is the code to load and map the numpy data:

```python
class full_nn:
    def __init__(self):
        self.data_dir = "E:\\numpy_arrays\\"        
        self.seq_ds = tf.data.Dataset.list_files(self.data_dir+"*\\*.npy", shuffle=False)        
        self.class_names = list(sorted([item.name for item in pathlib.Path(self.data_dir).glob('*')]))
        self.data_size = len(list(pathlib.Path(self.data_dir).glob('*\\*.npy')))
        self.train_size = int(self.data_size * 0.8)
        self.train_ds = self.seq_ds.take(self.train_size)
        self.test_ds = self.seq_ds.skip(self.train_size)
                    
nn = full_nn()

def get_label(file_path):    
    lbl = tf.strings.split(file_path, os.path.sep)[-2]
    return nn.class_names.index(lbl)

def process_image_batch(file_path):
    label = get_label(file_path) 
    #decode tf.string to string
    file_path = file_path.numpy()    
    file_path = file_path.decode('UTF-8') 
    seq = np.load(file_path)     
    return (seq, label)

def fix_shape(sequence, label):
    label.set_shape([])
    return sequence, label
        
train_ds = nn.train_ds.map(lambda x: tf.py_function(process_image_batch, [x], [tf.float32, tf.int32])).map(fix_shape)
test_ds = nn.test_ds.map(lambda x: tf.py_function(process_image_batch, [x], [tf.float32,  tf.int32])).map(fix_shape)
```

**Edit:** Not converting the tf.string produced this issue:

```python
TypeError: Target data is missing. Your model has `loss`: <keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy object at 0x0000029D9F1AFD30>, and therefore expects target data to be passed in `fit()`.
```

This is the neural network so far, influenced by [this](https://bleedai.com/human-activity-recognition-using-tensorflow-cnn-lstm/):

```python
model = keras.models.Sequential([
    layers.TimeDistributed(layers.Convolution2D(32, (7,7), strides=(2, 2),
      padding='same', activation='relu'), input_shape=(22,512,512,1)),
    layers.TimeDistributed(layers.Convolution2D(32, (3,3),
      kernel_initializer="he_normal", activation='relu')),
    layers.TimeDistributed(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=(2, 2))),
    
    layers.TimeDistributed(layers.Convolution2D(64, (3,3),
      padding='same', activation='relu')),
    layers.TimeDistributed(layers.Convolution2D(64, (3,3),
      padding='same', activation='relu')),
    layers.TimeDistributed(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=(2, 2))),

   layers.TimeDistributed(layers.Convolution2D(128, (3,3),
      padding='same', activation='relu')),
   layers.TimeDistributed(layers.Convolution2D(128, (3,3),
      padding='same', activation='relu')),
   layers.TimeDistributed(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=(2, 2))),

   layers.TimeDistributed(layers.Convolution2D(256, (3,3),
      padding='same', activation='relu')),
   layers.TimeDistributed(layers.Convolution2D(256, (3,3),
      padding='same', activation='relu')),
   layers.TimeDistributed(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=(2, 2))),

   layers.TimeDistributed(layers.Flatten()),

   
   layers.LSTM(512, return_sequences=False, dropout=0.2),   
   
   layers.Dense(nn.data_size, activation='softmax')
    
    ])
```

Here's how I build the model:

```python
loss = keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True)
optim = keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.001)
metrics=["accuracy"]

model.compile(loss=loss,optimizer=optim, metrics=metrics)
model.fit(train_ds, batch_size=8, epochs=5, verbose= 2, validation_data=test_ds)
```

Now here is the question: What causes the model fitting to fail? I get this error message:

```python
ValueError: slice index 0 of dimension 0 out of bounds. for '{{node strided_slice}} = StridedSlice[Index=DT_INT32, T=DT_INT32, begin_mask=0, ellipsis_mask=0, end_mask=0, new_axis_mask=0, shrink_axis_mask=1](Shape, strided_slice/stack, strided_slice/stack_1, strided_slice/stack_2)' with input shapes: [0], [1], [1], [1] and with computed input tensors: input[1] = <0>, input[2] = <1>, input[3] = <1>.
```

**Note:** My original question was what produced the mentioned "Target data is missing" error, which could be resolved by converting the tf.string into a string before loading the numpy file.

Comment: please try changing the batchsize as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56068924/14290697) and let us know if the issue still persists. Thank you!